# Android - Close app with System.exit

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

i want to exit my app with System.exit can anyone help me with any sample code?
i am looking to achieve this when the back or home button is pressed.

Comment: Using `System.exit()` is not recommended, use `Activity.finish()` instead.

Comment: thanks i know, i have heard about that. im in the learning process so i want to learn everything

Answer (score 1):

you can open dialog on back pressed override method like this.

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();

              DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                        dialog.cancel();

                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Exit or not ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
            }



        }
```

Comment: in your Activity you can override this method and put this code :)

Comment: In  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
Do not use getparent(). use (this) , or (getApplicationContext());

Comment: i just removed the alert, it worked thanks! is it possible to add a animation on the exit like a fade. it looks a little to quick on the exit.

Comment: i am also looking out for this kind of thing..... if i get around it...i will surely inform you.Accept the answer if you got correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a onclick listener there you can execute the `System.Exit` call:

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.Exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, i know how to set it up to a button i have in my app, but not to a external key.

Comment: what do you mean with external key?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in back button like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   super.onBackPressed();
   System.exit(0)
}
```

Edit: If you are on first activity you dont need to do so, just press back button OS will close your app automatically

Comment: no just add this code in your activity class, this method will be called when user press the back button of device